# Concatenation of strings doesn't give expected result

Tags: php

I'm trying to see if there's a "category" value in the URL, take that value and add it to hrefs, but what I get is, say, "4" added to the href, rather than "&category=4", which is what I'm after. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
        // if so, add it to the query
        if ($cat_ID) {
            $cat_string = "&category=" + $cat_ID;
        } else {
            $cat_string = "";
        }
    ?>
    <li><a href="?page_id=60&orderby=rand<?php echo $cat_string; ?>">Random</a></li>
    <li><a href="?page_id=60&orderby=title&order=ASC<?php echo $cat_string; ?>">Title Asc.</a></li>
    <li><a href="?page_id=60&orderby=title&order=DESC<?php echo $cat_string; ?>">Title Desc.</a></li>
    <li><a href="?page_id=60&orderby=date&order=ASC<?php echo $cat_string; ?>">Date Uploaded Asc.</a></li>
    <li><a href="?page_id=60&orderby=date&order=DESC<?php echo $cat_string; ?>">Date Uploaded Desc.</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP it's the `.` :

```
$cat_string = "&category=" . $cat_ID;
```

Also you can populate the variable to the double quoted string:

```
$cat_string = "&category=$cat_ID";
```

Manual:

- [String operators in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)
- [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Laziest language ever.

Comment: @GrantThomas Using $vars in a double quoted string is lent from bash or perl. Some guys argue PHP has lent too much from perl. ;) .. But I think this applies for the early days only. Today it has a quiet different feature set than perl

Answer (score 2):

You're doing string concatenation, use `.`:

```
$cat_string = "&category=" . $cat_ID;
```

`+` will forcefully cast it to a number, which apparently results in `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.` like

```
if ($cat_ID) {
    $cat_string = "&category = " . $cat_ID;
} else {
    $cat_string = "";
}
```

In `PHP` we concat strings with `.` and in `javascript` we concat with `+`.

Answer (score 0):

IN `PHP` string are concated with `.`.

`+` used in `Js`

```
"&category=" . $cat_ID;
```